# Deserialize a class with list of class containing a list: Error: "the collection is read-only"

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I'd like to serialize a class construct that contains a list of up to 16 sensors ( and additional a list with up to 4 PressureSensors), which contain a list with the coefficients of their function (and some more information like ID ...).

The PressureSensor thing is additional and just shows that there are some more collections in the module. Otherwise a

```
List<List<SimpleSensor>>
```

would have been sufficient.

The XML is created without problems, only deserialization fails

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Module xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SingleSensors>
    <SSensor>
      <ID>Sensor1</ID>
      <Function>
        <double>0</double>
        <double>1</double>
      </Function>
    </SSensor>
    <SSensor>
      <ID>Sensor2</ID>
      <Function>
        <double>0</double>
        <double>1</double>
      </Function>
    </SSensor>
  </SingleSensors>
  <PressureSensors>
    <PSensor>
      <ID>Pressure1</ID>
      <Function>
        <double>0</double>
        <double>1</double>
      </Function>
    </PSensor>
    <PSensor>
      <ID>Pressure2</ID>
      <Function>
        <double>0</double>
        <double>1</double>
      </Function>
    </PSensor>
  </PressureSensors>
</Module>
```

The Class construct is as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleSensor
{
     [XmlElement("ID")]
     public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Function")]
    public Collection<double> Coefficient { get; set; }

    //## Constructor:
    public SimpleSensor()
    {
        Id = "00";
        double[] content = new double[2] { 0, 1 };
        Coefficient = new  Collection<double>(content);           
    }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Module")]
public class MostModule
{
    [XmlArray("SingleSensors")]
    [XmlArrayItem("SSensor")]
    public List<SimpleSensor> Sensor { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("PressureSensors")]
    [XmlArrayItem("PSensor")]
    public List<SimpleSensor> PressureSensor { get; set; }



    //## Constructor:
    public MostModule()
    {            
        //Initialise SimpleSensors with 2 Sensors
        SimpleSensor[] SensorArray = new SimpleSensor[2];                        
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            SensorArray[i] = new SimpleSensor();
            SensorArray[i].Id = "Sensor" + (i + 1);
        }
        Sensor = new List<SimpleSensor>(SensorArray);
        PressureSensor = new List<SimpleSensor>(SensorArray);
    }

    public static MostModule Deserialize(string fileName)
    {
        MostModule Sensors;
        XmlSerializer myXMLSerial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MostModule));
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            Sensors = (MostModule)myXMLSerial.Deserialize(sr);                   
        }
        return Sensors;           
    }
```

When I tried to Serialize this class it works properly, but the deserialization stops with an error and the inner exception:
NotSupportedException       "The collection is read-only."

I have tried the same with hard defined sensors and there is no problem in Serializing and deserializing:

```
public class MostModule
{
    public SimpleSensor Sensor1 { get; set; }
    public SimpleSensor Sensor2 { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to serialize the module this way, or do I have to program it all with hard defined Variables that i have to put into a list from the main?

Or is there any other suggestion for saving and loading my data in this kind of construction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following List<> objects

```
 [XmlRoot("SingleSensors")]
    public class SimpleSensor
    {
        [XmlElement("SSensor")]
        public List<SSensor> sSensor { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("PressureSensors")]
    public class PressureSensors
    {
        [XmlElement("PSensor")]
        public List<SSensor> sSensor { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Woah, i think this works! Well done! just added this to your first comment and it works all well together!

Comment: Sorry I missed this step the 1st time.  Been doing a lot of these XML serializations recently.  Getting real good at it.

Comment: Right now i implemented it into my project and after some initialisition routine the class is written properly and the reading was also without errors, thank you very much!!    - Usually i try to get to the things by myself, but this time it was really hard because stackoverflow didn't had something similar

Answer (score 0):

Define `SimpleSensor.Coefficient` as a plain array and it will work:

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleSensor
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Function")]
    public double[] Coefficient { get; set; }

    //## Constructor:
    public SimpleSensor()
    {
        Id = "00";
        double[] content = new double[2] { 0, 1 };
        Coefficient = content;           
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to program according to microsoft  managed Recommended rules - and these say that it is not allowed to have arrays in Properties

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MostModule));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            MostModule MostModule = (MostModule)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }


    [XmlRoot("Function")]
    public class Function
    {
        [XmlElement("double")]
        public List<int> m_double {get;set;}
    }

    public class SSensor
    {
        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Function")]
        public Function Coefficient { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("SingleSensors")]
    public class SimpleSensor
    {
        [XmlElement("SSensor")]
        public SSensor sSensor { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("PressureSensors")]
    public class PressureSensors
    {
        [XmlElement("PSensor")]
        public SSensor sSensor { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("Module")]
    public class MostModule
    {
        [XmlElement("SingleSensors")]
        public SimpleSensor Sensor { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PressureSensors")]
        public PressureSensors PressureSensor { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but that does not cover a bunch of sensors or pressuresensors. It only gives me the first Sensor of each kind